# problema al compilar Xamarin en VSComunity 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xamarin.forms

Recién acabo de instalar VS 2019 en mi maquina Windows 10 SO 32bits,resulta que no puedo compilar ninguna aplicación, al inicio me apareció [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le dí en reparar y finalizó correcto, pero al compilar el proyecto de Android manda

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
```

Error       Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): El ejecutable especificado no es una aplicación válida para esta plataforma de sistema operativo.
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CompileNativeAssembly.RunAssembler(Config config)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AsyncTaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1`1.b__0()  App1.Android

En plataforma destino tengo Android Oreo 8.1, en Manifiesto tengo versión mínima 8.1 y Maxima 8.1
ya ejecuté limpieza, recompilé.., nosé que más pueda hacer
Ésta fue la última posibilidad de que funcionara, pero quedó descartada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que tu problema puede estar en que tenes sistema operativo de 32 bits y deberias ver si se soluciona desde el manifiest -> opciones de Android -> Avanzadas, y ahi elegis el destino del microprocesador.

Comment: Gracias Ramiro, pero esta vez se debería agregar alas especificaciones de Android en Xamarin, no es compatible con Windows 10 x86 !. Hice hasta lo imposible y por ningún medio de configuración permite compilar. A formatear todo ..